# why different digit number won't work in this python code?

Tags: python

I try to use python to prompt user to enter different number, and keep  the largest one, and finish when user enter "done". but I find out it can not work with different digit of number. for example, 1st entry: 91, 2nd:94, it will run well. but 1st entry:91 and 2nd:100, it can not record 100 as the largest number. did somebody know what's going on? thank you so much!

code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:

    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try: int (num)
    except: 
        print "Please enter a numeric number"
    if largest is None and smallest is None: 
        largest = num
        smallest = num
        #print "l", largest
        #print "s", smallest
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
        print largest, num

    #if num < smallest:
       # smallest = num
       # print "s2", smallest


    print num

    print "Maximum is ", largest
    #print "Minimum is ", smallest
```

Comment: Have you tried retaining the result of your test?

Comment: The problem is with `int(num)` -- this doesn't change the type of `num` permanently.

Comment: Yes, I got it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing ASCII comparisons, not numeric. you need to actually assign something like `number = int(num)` and use `number` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not converting `num` to an integer, so it's using string comparison rather than numeric comparison.  Change:

```
try: int (num)
```

to:

```
try:
    num = int(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of problems. Take a look at this, maybe you can incorporate it into your own code?

```
largest = 0

while True:
    prompt = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        num = int(prompt)
        if num > largest:
            largest = num
    except:
        if prompt == 'done':
            break

print largest
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a string. So when you compare `num > largest` you are using string (alphabetical) comparison. You want to compare numbers. The easiest way would be to simply rewrite the comparion to `int(num) > int(largest)`.

`try: int (num) ...` already checks if the input is a number but it does not change the value of the variable.

Note: `except` without an exception type is generally not a good idea. You should explicitly write down the exception you want to catch: `ValueError`